# Как определить временную зону зашедшего на сайт?

Tags: timezone, php, время

На сайте есть новости с указанием времени, когда они были опубликованы. Время указывается по Москве, например 12:00. Если человек зайдет допустим из Лондона, то он увидит, что новость опубликована в полдень, хотя у него еще только 8 утра(если не ошибаюсь).

У меня два вопроса.

1. Как определить часовой пояс.
2. Как лучше в таком случае отображать время, если человек зашел из другой временной зоны? Может добавлять приписку "время по Москве"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучше всего, не нагружать свой сервер лишними вычислениями, а просто отдавать время в unixtime, и силами браузера, на js уже преобразовывать его в понятное человеку время, а js тем самым уже сам подгонит его под часовой пояс пользователя.

Answer (score 5):

Вот варианты решения:

- Ну например: [smart-ip.net](http://ru.smart-ip.net/anounce-geoip-update-timezones-added) - там есть сервис по определению часового пояса по IP, ограничения 5000 запросов с одного айпи в сутки. Запросы через http/https, возвращает XML или JSON. *(Я думаю не стоит так возиться с часовыми поясами...)*
- Спрашивать у пользователя часовой пояс / задавать этот часовой пояс в настройках профиля. *(Этот способ я больше предпочитаю)*
- Менять всё это дело в JS.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто в поиске изначально хорошего решения.

Просто возьмите за правило что любая программа должна работать во временной зоне UTC, любая запись в БД должна быть в UTC, так просто удобней.

Выставляем UTC, чтобы все операции внутри скриптов были в этой зоне:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

И уже потом для каждого пользователя отдельно, на основе его таймзоны будем конвертировать.

Эта переменная задаёт часовой пояс посетителя в который будем конвертировать.

```
$set_user_timezone='Europe/Kiev';
```

В переменную $set_user_timezone можно вписывать временную зону которую определяет GeoIP

И вот функция:

```
function local_datetime($convert_date){
global $set_user_timezone;
$date = new DateTime($convert_date);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($set_user_timezone));
return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

И выполняем:

```
echo local_datetime(Сюда вписываем дату и время в UTC которую будем конвертировать в юзерский пояс);
```